# Как получить ответ из броадкаста??

Tags: java, android

Работаю с блютузом.Прежде чем получить список доступных устрйств проверяю на  то что включен ли блютуз.если да то получаю список.если нет то включаю и получаю список.Но метод включения регистрирует блютуз но не отвечает за то что блютуз включился или нет .Как быть ? как ждать ответа от броадкаста

Comment: ну покажите код, у BT есть свой State который изменяется, мб вы не хендлите его